# Why does Office.Interop use type dynamic

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, dynamic-typing

Why does VSTO use the type `dynamic` for many return values and why are they inconsistent?  The `dynamic` return type seems to cause additional work.  `Var` variables are often not automatically typed properly, and explicit types, which are not always obvious to infer, must be used for Intellisense to work.

For example, the first var below is typed properly to `Excel.ListObject`, but the second `var row` is not typed to `Excel.ListRow` automatically.  Instead, `foreach (Excel.ListRow row in ...` is required to get the row properties and methods.  It wasn't hard to figure out `Excel.ListRow` was the proper type, but it did take looking at a couple of pages of documentation.

```
var incomeEntry = worksheet.ListObjects["IncomeEntry"];
foreach (var row in incomeEntry.ListRows)
...
```

Is this legacy, maybe? Or, is this the wave of the future?